# Netbeans 8: Project Properties -> Change EJB Java EE Version

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans, netbeans-8

I created a maven EJB project on Netbeans 8.0.1, when I originally created the project I didn't specify a Server for it to run on and left the Java EE Version on 5 (Thinking I'll change it later).

Now I want to change the Project properties so run uses Java EE version 6.

- I cant do that. I tried looking for the **(project-folder)/nbproject/project.properties** file, it does not exist.
- I tried re-checking out the project from git, there is only  **(project-folder)/src**, a **pom.xml** and a **.gitingore**  file, Yet Neatbeans knows this project is configured to use Java EE Version 5.

This also results in the maven build breaking:

***Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ejb-plugin:2.3:ejb (default-ejb) on project : Error assembling EJB: META-INF/ejb-jar.xml is required for ejbVersion 2.x***

Any help, on how I can change the Java EE Version so it reflects on both Netbeans 8 and the maven build?

May the force be with you!

Comment: In Netbeans, if you right-click on the project and go to `Properties -> Run -> Java EE Settings`, does it allow you to change your project settings from EE 5 to 6?

Comment: @whitlaaa No it doesn't, have you had success in doing that?

Comment: Typically yes, though I believe it depends on how you create your project. It would look something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/klF2Xi5.png). If you can't see that, this [bug ticket](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242754) sounds like it may be similar to what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to  `<project-folder>/nbproject/project.properties` update the j2ee version:

```
j2ee.platform=1.6
```

for maven you should use:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone!

I ended up solving it by including an ejb-jar.xml with the module which specified an ejb 3.0 version.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ejb-jar xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         version = "3.0" 
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">
</ejb-jar>
```

Built properly and its all systems go!

Thanks @whitlaaa